# How do I fix this broken stasis pod?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

While exploring an asteroid field I stumbled across a **Damaged Stasis Pod**:

[image: FTL Screenshot clipping showing 'Damaged Stasis Pod' as an augmentation on a ship]

In this instance, I found the pod just before leaving sector 7 and ended up finished the game before discovering what it does, if anything. I recall having seen it once before, but in that case was destroyed shortly afterwards.

So, for the next time I find it, how do I repair it (as the description implies is possible)?
And what does fixing it do?

Comment: Another route of finishing this quest can be found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86056/wheres-the-secret-sector

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's an event where some Zoltan scientists will ask if they can run some tests on your ship and crew.  If you have this pod, when you meet with these scientists, you can instead choose to allow them to inspect the pod.

From the pod:

> You'll gain a new crewmember, who is of a race that preceeded the Rock people.  He will ask you to embark on a quest near the Rock homeworld.  He is sort of a cross between Rock and Human, and has a "Lockdown" ability that is unique.

Once you've completed this quest stage, you'll get another for the Rock Homeworld sector.  If you've already passed this or don't have it on your route, you're out of luck.  If you manage to finish this stage of the quest:

> You will unlock the "unidentified cruiser" - the Crystalline Cruiser in the ship hangar.