# Where's the Secret Sector?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

One of the rockman ship achievements is "Find the Secret Sector".  There doesn't seem to be room on the map for a secret sector.

What's the secret sector?

Comment: Another route of finishing this quest can be found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83374/how-do-i-fix-this-broken-stasis-pod#autocomment323795

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "Secret Sector" is a location you can visit while following the quest to repair the [broken Stasis Pod.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/83376/13845)  It is home to a secret race, and their [secret ship.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/83362/13845)

Here's a good video walkthrough of the events you'll need to encounter in order to get there.  Having the Rock cruiser's Rock Plating makes part of this easier, but it's still a challenging set of events to trigger properly: